# Update xml in mock response using SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using SoapUI to mock a service, and I'm returning different stored XMl's based on the request using a groovy script.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def groovyUtils = new GroovyUtils(context)

def xmlParser = new XmlParser()
def responseContent

def requestXmlHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(mockRequest.getRequestContent())
requestXmlHolder.declareNamespace("v01", "http://www.zoot.com/data_type/ZE_Messaging/v01")
def email = (requestXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//v01:Request[1]/v01:Email[1]"))

def responsePath = "C:/MockService/Responses"

switch(email){
    case ~/(?i).*acceptall.*/:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath + "/acceptall-response.xml" )
        break
    case ~/(?i).*acceptspl.*/:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath + "/acceptspl-response.xml" )
        break
    case ~/(?i).*acceptmpl.*/:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath  + "/acceptmpl-response.xml" )
        break
    case ~/(?i).*decline.*/:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath + "/decline-response.xml" )
        break
    default:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath + "/custom-response.xml" )
        break
}

context.content = XmlUtil.serialize(responseContent)
```

This works fine, but now I'm trying to update one of the nodes of this response before, more precisely I'd like to add the current date in that script as there's a node in the xml which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v01="http://www.whatever.com/data_type/ZE_Messaging/v01">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v01:Response>
         <v01:RequestID>eeee</v01:RequestID>
         <v01:TransactionID>?</v01:TransactionID>
         <v01:CostumerID>?</v01:CostumerID>
         <v01:TransactionDateTime>?</v01:TransactionDateTime>
         <v01:FirstName>?</v01:FirstName>
         <v01:MiddleName>?</v01:MiddleName>
         <v01:Name>?</v01:Name>
         <v01:MaidenName>?</v01:MaidenName>
         <v01:Gender>?</v01:Gender>
         <v01:DateOfBirth>?</v01:DateOfBirth>
         <v01:Decision>ACCEPTALL</v01:Decision>
         <v01:DecisionText>?</v01:DecisionText>
         <v01:DecisionReasonCodes>?</v01:DecisionReasonCodes>
         <v01:ErrorCode>?</v01:ErrorCode>
         <v01:ErrorDescription>?</v01:ErrorDescription>
         <v01:AdditionalDetails>
            <v01:Data category="?" attribute="?">?</v01:Data>
         </v01:AdditionalDetails>
      </v01:Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the script if I do this, just before setting the context.content

```
def soapenv =  new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
def v01 = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://www.whatever.com/data_type/ZE_Messaging/v01")

log.info responseContent[soapenv.Body][v01.Response][v01.RequestID].text()
```

I will get the 'eeee'

So basically what I need is how to set that to a different thing from what I getting from the file itself before setting that context.content

Comment: It's unclear what You'd like to do.

Comment: @Opal, I would like to update the xml I get from my file systeme, and put the current date in the TransactionDateTime before. I update the question

Comment: Can You please add full response, e.g. with namespaces, that is a valid XML file?

Comment: Yes, @Opal, it's a valid XML file that I add to the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just in case this messy question could be of some help. for updating for example RequestID that comes in the xml retrieved from the file system set to 'eeee' to 'iiii' the script should be this one

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def groovyUtils = new GroovyUtils(context)

def xmlParser = new XmlParser()
def responseContent

def requestXmlHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(mockRequest.getRequestContent())
requestXmlHolder.declareNamespace("v01", "http://www.whatever.com/data_type/ZE_Messaging/v01")
def email = (requestXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//v01:Request[1]/v01:Email[1]"))

def responsePath = "C:/inetpub/ZootMock/Responses"

switch(email){
    case ~/(?i).*acceptall.*/:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath + "/acceptall-response.xml" )
        break
    case ~/(?i).*acceptspl.*/:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath + "/acceptspl-response.xml" )
        break
    case ~/(?i).*acceptmpl.*/:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath  + "/acceptmpl-response.xml" )
        break
    case ~/(?i).*decline.*/:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath + "/decline-response.xml" )
        break
    default:
        responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath + "/custom-response.xml" )
        break
}
responseContent = xmlParser.parse( responsePath + "/acceptall-response.xml" )

def soapenv =  new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
def v01 = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://www.whatever.com/data_type/ZE_Messaging/v01")

responseContent[soapenv.Body][v01.Response][v01.RequestID][0].value = 'iii' 

context.content = XmlUtil.serialize(responseContent)
```

So the key thing was

```
def soapenv =  new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
def v01 = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://www.whatever.com/data_type/ZE_Messaging/v01")

responseContent[soapenv.Body][v01.Response][v01.RequestID][0].value = 'iii'
```

Thanks